# Calling a c# webservice from classic ASP

Tags: c#, web-services, asp-classic

I tried the following to retrieve the result of the web service:

```
<%  
    Dim oRequest
    Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    oRequest.setOption(2) = SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
    oRequest.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000

    msURL = "http://[0.0.0.0]/contale/customer.asmx/GetInfoFromWhitesPages"

    msSOAP = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Body>"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "<GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse   xmlns=""http://[0.0.0.0]/Contale/"">"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "<phone>4504656253</phone>"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "</GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse>"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Body>"
    msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Envelope>"

    oRequest.Open "POST", msURL, False
    oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    oRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "[Some Url]"
    oRequest.send msSOAP
    Response.Write oRequest.ResponseBody
%>
```

But the results shows has: ????????????????›???4???????????????????????†???????????????????????????????????†?4???????????????????????????????????

I also tried the following:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<%
    Dim objHTTP, strEnvelope
    Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    strEnvelope = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" 
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "<soap:Body>"
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "<GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse xmlns='http://[0.0.0.0]/Contale'>"
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "<phone>4504656253</phone>"
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "</GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse>"
    strEnvelope = strEnvelope & "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    Dim url
    url = "http://[0.0.0.0]/contale/customer.asmx"
    With objHTTP
        .Open "post", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://[0.0.0.0]/contale/GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse"
        .send strEnvelope
    End With

    Dim strResponse
    strResponse = objHTTP.responseXML.Text
    If (strResponse = "") Then
        Response.Write("Invalid user")
    Else
        Response.Write(strResponse)
    End If
%>
</body>
</html>
```

But, I'm getting this :

```
soap:ClientSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://[0.0.0.0]/contale/GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Here is the code of my WebService:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CustomersInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://[0.0.0.0]/Contale/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public CustomerData GetInfoFromWhitesPages(string phone)
        {
            var customer = new CustomerData();

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36 Other");

            var content =                       webClient.DownloadString("http://www.whitepages.com/phone/" + phone);

            const string infoStart = "<div class=\"address-card\">";

            if (content.Contains(infoStart))
            {
                var startPos = content.IndexOf("<div class=\"address-card\">", StringComparison.Ordinal) + infoStart.Length;
                var endPos = content.IndexOf("</div>", startPos, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var info = content.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).TrimEnd().TrimStart();

                info = info.Replace("\n", "").Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "");
                string[] tabInfo = Regex.Split(info, "<br />");
                string name = tabInfo[0];
                string address = tabInfo[2];
                string city = tabInfo[3].Split(' ')[0].Replace(",", "");
                string province = tabInfo[3].Split(' ')[1];
                string zip = tabInfo[3].Split(' ')[2] + " " + tabInfo[3].Split(' ')[3];

                customer.Name = name;
                customer.Address = address;
                customer.City = city;
                customer.Province = province;
                customer.Zip = zip;
            }
            return customer;
        }

        public struct CustomerData
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Address;
            public string City;
            public string Province;
            public string Zip;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Try Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"), and also check the encoding of your Classic ASP results page.  Open it Notepad, (or just about any text editor other than VS), select Save As from the File menu, and if ASCI is selected in the Encoding box change it to UTF-8

Comment: Also, it is highly unlikely that the request requires the `GetInfoFromWhitesPagesResponse` parameter. Rather I'd expect this comes inside the response and the request should just use `GetInfoFromWhitesPages`. As for invalid SOAPAction - read the correct value from the service's WSDL.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I did small modification to my second script and was able to achieve what I was looking for.

Comment: Please add answer describing the solution for others to see and learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

First add codepage=65001
Second tell the browser you are sending utf-8

The ? Chars are displayed because the browser as well as the server does not know how to handle the response